# Can carplay's CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication to trigger UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication to connect and active

Tags: iphone, carplay

I'm develop an application that support CarPlay. There are one case that the user open app in CarPlay, so the main scene of app in iPhone is not connected and active. Is there any method of trigger main scene to be connected and active and bring to foreground when open in CarPlay?

Comment: Check in this [sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/integrating_carplay_with_your_music_app) : the CarPlay scene send messages to the iPhone app about what is going on. This can give you a start

Comment: As far as I understand you want to open the app on the phone when the CarPlay app is launched? This is not possible. I suggest you trigger any logic that you expect to run in the main app's scene activation manually from the CarPlay scene.